# FormatException: Invalid character (at character 308135) while decoding base64 String in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, base64, decode

I have an base64 string which has unicode such as \u,\n and so on. while trying to decode base64 string,, I am getting `FormatException: Invalid character (at character 308135)` pointing to `\u`.
This is how my code look like:

```
 var formTemplate = "asdaskdsd788\uhvsajdasd\u==sdsd..."; //base64 string
  try {
    var base64decode = utf8.decode(base64.decode(formTemplate));
  } catch (e) {
    print(e);
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

I end up using [strig_escape](https://pub.dev/packages/string_unescape) plugin. Any other solution are welcome.
eg.

```
var base64String = "21dsdsadas\udsads=\udsd";
var decodeString = unescape(base64String);
```